# Can a single aws cli command do 'aws s3 cp from a single origin file to multiple destination files'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I need to clone a cross-bucket copied file as below:

```
# 1. copying file A -> file_B
aws s3 cp s3://bucket_a/file_A s3://bucket_b/file_B

# 2. cloning file_B -> file_C
aws s3 cp s3://bucket_b/file_B s3://bucket_b/file_C
```

Is there shorter/better way to do so?

EDIT:

- `bucket_a` -> `bucket_b` is cross region (`bucket_a` and `bucket_b` are on the other side of earth)
- `file_B` and `file_C` have the same name but with different prefix (so it's like `bucket_b/prefix_a/file_B` and `bucket_b/prefix_b/file_B`)
- in summary, I want the `file_A` in a origin `bucket_a` to be copied in two places of the destination `bucket_b`, looking for a way to copy once instead of copy twice

Comment: What is your actual desire? Is it to copy one file to multiple destinations? Do they need to be renamed (as in the above example), or do you wish to keep the same name? Why are you copying B->C instead of A->C? Feel free to edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can copy multiple files, but each file is only copied once.

If your goal is to replicate the contents of a bucket to another bucket, you could use [Cross-Region Replication (CRR) - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) but it only works between regions and it only copies objects that are stored *after* CRR is activated.

You can always write a script or program yourself using an AWS SDK to do whatever you wish.

Comment: is CRR instantly applied? I mean If I upload a file in a region, how long it would take to appear on the other region? Is there a way to know if replication is done and my file is available?

Comment: While not instantaneous, it is fairly quick. You can do some experimentation to determine the typical time. I think the only way to know if it is complete is to list the destination bucket, or try to access the relicated file.